# Angular2 Error : Property 'geocoder' does not exist on type 'ControlStatic'

Tags: angular

I make my first angular2 app with leaflets.
I installed these npm packages : Leaflet & leaflet-control-geocoder
I have an error when I save my component and I don't know what he means by

> Property 'geocoder' does not exist on type 'ControlStatic'.

**Code of my component**

```
// <reference path="../../typings/leaflet/leaflet.d.ts"/>

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Map } from 'leaflet';
import { MapServices } from './Map.services';
import  'leaflet-control-geocoder';

@Component({
  selector: 'map',
  pipes: [],
  providers: [MapServices],
  templateUrl: './Map.template.html'
})

export class map  implements OnInit {
    private mapService: MapServices;

    constructor(mapService: MapServices) {
       this.mapService = mapService;
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        // Initialisation de la carte (mapid étant le div qui recevra la carte)
        var map = new L.Map('mapid', {layers: [this.mapService.baseMaps.OpenStreetMap]}).setView([50.09418, 5.77521], 16);

        L.control.layers(this.mapService.baseMaps).addTo(map); 
        L.control.scale({position:'bottomright'}).addTo(map);
        var geocoder = L.Control.geocoder().addTo(map);

    } 
}
```